# All Protractor tests fail after Chrome browser updated to version 88

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Has anyone encounter the issue where updating to Chrome browser 88 causes all Protractor e2e tests to fail if the test system is not physically logged into?  If I rollback the Chrome browser to 87, all the tests run perfectly fine whether your logged into the test system or not.

Chrome Version:  88
ChromeDriver Version:  88

All tests fail due to the following error:

```
[1612915519.938][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1612915519.939][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1612915529.939][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

If I were to log back into the Windows test system, the tests will then start to run fine.

Comment: I recently found out about super new vulnerability that was spread during 2020. Don't know much details, but I know that it was fundamentally different than anything else IT world has seen before and affected multiple layers of multiple if not all operating systems and softwares. The chrome fixes were released in v88. You can potentially correlate your problem to this, because having access to browser while not logged in is a security flaw. But it's still just a guess

Comment: can you please try executing ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update  in terminal?

Comment: I get:
`[09:29:40] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar up to date
[09:29:40] I/update - chromedriver: file exists D:\git-repos\e2e-test-framework\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.zip
[09:29:40] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.zip
[09:29:40] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.exe up to date`